# Как посмотреть, насколько % загружен процессор в Debian'e?

Tags: время, процессор

Как посмотреть, насколько % загружен процессор в Debian'e?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Команда `top` в консоли

[image: Скриншот]

> Цитата из мануала:
>
> 2c. CPU States
>          The  CPU  states  are  shown in the Summary Area. They are always
>   shown as a percentage and are for the
>   time
>          between now and the last refresh.
>
> ```
>     us  --  User CPU time
>       The time the CPU has spent running users' processes that are not
> ```
>
> niced.
>
> ```
>     sy  --  System CPU time
>       The time the CPU has spent running the kernel and its processes.
>
>     ni  --  Nice CPU time
>       The time the CPU has spent running users' proccess that have been
> ```
>
> niced.
>
> ```
>     wa  --  iowait
>       Amount of time the CPU has been waiting for I/O to complete.
>
>     hi  --  Hardware IRQ
>       The amount of time the CPU has been servicing hardware
> ```
>
> interrupts.
>
> ```
>     si  --  Software Interrupts
>       The amount of time the CPU has been servicing software
> ```
>
> interrupts.
>
> ```
>     st  --  Steal Time
>       The amount of CPU 'stolen' from this virtual machine by the
> ```
>
> hypervisor for other tasks (such  as 
>   running
>             another virtual machine).

Comment: @Shock, а как понять насколько % нагружен? Вот скрин http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1360078525-clip-12kb.png

Comment: Я добавил скрин в комментарий. Смотрите выше, а именно кусок Cpu(s)

Ну и вашем случае можно очень быстро в уме приблизительно приплюсовать первые несколько строчек)